# Alternating File Contents on startup (sh bash)

Tags: bash, sh

In my /etc/rc.local file I have this code:

```
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

value='cat  /var/www/key.txt'
if ["$value" = "0"] then 
    sed -i 's/0/1/g' /var/www/key.txt
fi
if ["$value"= "1"] then
    sed -i 's/1/0/g' /var/www/key.txt
fi 
mpg321 /var/www/sounds/startup.mp3 >  /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
exit 0
```

The problem area is the part from 'value' to the last 'fi'.

What I want to happen is for the file contents of /var/www/key.txt to alternate on each startup between '1' and '0'. This doesn't seem to happen.

The audio does play, so the file is being run. I assume there is something wrong with my IF statements?

Any ideas?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Use http://shellcheck.net - there are several syntax errors in your script. In bash, to read a file into a variable, you can use `contents=$(< filename)`.

Comment: I never knew that apostrophes and spaces could break so much. Thanks for the guidance, it works nicely now!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are simple errors that could be fixed by following the recommendations in the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few wrong things in your script. The following is your script but with my fixes

```
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
   printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

value=`cat  /var/www/key.txt`
if [ "$value" = "0" ]; then
   sed -i 's/0/1/g' /var/www/key.txt
fi
if [ "$value" = "1" ]; then
   sed -i 's/1/0/g' /var/www/key.txt
fi
mpg321 /var/www/sounds/startup.mp3 >  /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
value='cat  /var/www/key.txt'
```

into

```
value=`cat /var/www/key.txt`
```

Apostrophes (') as in the first version just quote the string, setting the variable `value` to the literal string `cat  /var/www/key.txt` which is obviously not what you want. If you want the string to be executed as a command and its output substituted in its place you need to use backticks (`).

Comment: Use `$(...)`, not backticks.